# Error: NextRouter was not mounted when I use use client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When I use `use client` I get `Error: NextRouter was not mounted error` but when I remove `use client` I get this error

**Error when I remove `use client`:**

ReactServerComponentsError:

> You're importing a component that needs useState. It only works in a
> Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client",
> so they're Server Components by default. Learn more:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials

My folder structure:

> app/nft-details/page.tsx

**Page.tsx:**

```
'use client';
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

//INTERNAL IMPORT
import { Button, Category, Brand } from "../../components/components-index";
import NFTDetailsPage from "../../NFTDetailsPage/NFTDetailsPage";

//IMPORT SMART CONTRACT DATA
import { NFTMarketplaceContext } from "../../Context/NFTMarketplaceContext";
import Navbar from "../../components/Navbar/navbar";
import Footer from "../../components/Footer/footer";

const NFTDetails = () => {
    const { currentAccount } = useContext(NFTMarketplaceContext);
    const [nft, setNft] = useState({
        image: "",
        tokenId: "",
        name: "",
        owner: "",
        price: "",
        seller: "",
    });


    const router = useRouter();
    console.log("Query:", router.query);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!router.isReady) return;
        setNft(router.query);
    }, [router.isReady]);

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar/>
            <NFTDetailsPage nft={nft} />
            <Category />
            <Brand />
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default NFTDetails;
```

I want to pass parameters from a search page to a details page, using a Link component like `<Link href={{ pathname: "nft-details", query: el}} key={i+1}>`. In the details page, I want to receive these parameters as an object so that I can display them in my NFT details page.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you should import the `useRouter` from the following package:

```js
import {useRouter} from "next/navigation";
```

Comment: Thanks I did tried that also but then it says router.query: undefined

Comment: good point. consider using the `useSearchParams` from the same package